# Is it possible to know which Events a given transaction triggered?

Tags: json-rpc, events, logs

I've noticed the [GetTransactionReceipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) function returns an array of logs that were created as a result of the transaction being processed. However, I wonder if there is a way to get a list of Events that a transaction created during its execution, since those two don't seem to be synonymous. Or does GetTransactionReceipt already return both logs and Events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are really just a layer on top of logs. The logs *are* the events, but they need to be interpreted as such in your code. That said, I haven't found a very easy way in `web3.js` to parse the logs using a contract's ABI to get at them in log form.

Read http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events for some background on the relationship between logs and events.